# Inserting a table that consists 2 rows and 4 columns to the right next to the image in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]I am struggling inserting a table that consists of 2 rows and 4 columns into the table while I keep the 2 rows and 4 columns of the bottom table of the image.
right next to the image in the table
Is there anyway to put it in? 
I am new to html, so the structure of the table might look so not organized because it includes lots of class and id for jquery.

thank you,

(p.s: I am sorry that the language consists of Korean because I am doing it for the school project)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>예약 내역 조회</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .outer{
        width:860px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }   

    .main-title{
        margin-top: 35px; 
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 900;
    }   
    hr.garo{
        border: 1px solid #757272;
        margin: 17px 0px 0px 0px;
    }   

    #tableMain{
        width:800px;
        border:1px solid lightgray;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing:0px;
        margin-top:40px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    table{
        width: 100%;
    }
    th{
        margin-top: 10px;
        background: lightgray;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    th,td {

         text-align: center;
         border: 1px solid lightgray;
         border-left: none ;
         border-right: none;
    }


    #pop{
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        font-size: 10px;
        text-align:left
    }

    #tableMain > img{
         display:block;
         width: 200px; 
         height: 100px;
         justify-content: center;
    }



    #bor{
        border: 1px solid gray;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .pay{
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.418);
    }

    .breakrow{
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:10px;

    }

    input{
        background-color: #ffc107;
        color:white;
        border-radius: 2px;

    }

    #sep{
        border: 1px solid gray; 
        border-collapse: collapse;

    }

    #space{
        margin-left: 20px;
        width:60;
        height:25px;
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:5px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        color:white;
    }



    .arrow {
            float: left;
            border: 10px solid transparent;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            border-top-color: lightgray;
            transition: 350ms;
            position: absolute;
    }
    .accordion-head.open{
            background: white;
    }
    .accordion-head.open1{
            background: #eee;
    }
    .accordion-head.open .arrow {
            margin-top: -10px;
            transform: rotate(180deg);

    }
    </style>


    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="outer"> 
            <span class="main-title">예약 내역 조회</span>
            <hr class="garo">

            <table id="tableMain" class="accordion" style="text-align:center;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th style="height:40px;">예약 번호</th>
                          <th style="height:40px;">대여 기간</th>
                          <th style="height:40px; padding-right:90px;">지점명</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
       <tr class="accordion-head breakrow open">
        <td><div class="arrow"></div> 1</td>
        <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
        <td >강남지점-강남지점 <input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""></td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-body" style="display: none;">
        <td colspan="3">
          <table id="sep">
            <tbody>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor" rowspan="1" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg">

                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">차량 대여요금</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">보험료</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor">총 결제 금액</td>
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Number #2 -->
      <tr class="accordion-head breakrow open" >
        <td><div class="arrow"></div> 1</td>
        <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">강남지점-강남지점 <input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-body" style="display: none;">
        <td colspan="3">
          <table id="sep">
            <tbody>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor" rowspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">차량 대여요금</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">보험료</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor">총 결제 금액</td>
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-head breakrow open">
        <td><div class="arrow"></div> 1</td>
        <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
        <td>강남지점-강남지점 <input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-body" style="display: none;">
        <td colspan="3">
          <table id="sep">
            <tbody>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor" rowspan="5" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">차량 대여요금</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">보험료</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor" colspan="2">총 결제 금액</td>
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" >52,520원</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-head breakrow open">
        <td><div class="arrow"></div> 1</td>
        <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
        <td>강남지점-강남지점 <input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-body" style="display: none;">
        <td colspan="3">
          <table id="sep">
            <tbody>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor" colspan="0">
                <img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg">
                </td>
                <td>asdasd</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">차량 대여요금</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">보험료</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td> 
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor">총 결제 금액</td>
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr> 


           </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
    <script>


    $(document).on('click', '.accordion-head', function(){


    $('.accordion-head').removeClass('open');
    if (!$(this).hasClass('open')){
      $(this).addClass('open1'); 
    }
    else{ 
      $('.accordion-head').removeClass('open'); 
      $(this).addClass('close'); 
    }
    $('.accordion-body').slideUp("fast");
    $(this).next().slideDown("fast"); 

    $(document).on('dblclick', '.accordion-head', function(){

      if (!$(this).hasClass('open')){
          $('.accordion-head').removeClass('open1');
    }
    else{
      $('.accordion-head').removeClass('open'); 
      $(this).addClass('close'); 
    }
    $('.accordion-body').slideUp("fast");
    });
    });




    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May be you could add a picture / visual of what it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I got what you wanted it to look like, but how about this?

I just separated the image to the table with text and moved it in another `<td>` inside `<tr>` with the image...

this part right here:

```
<tr id="pop">
  <!---- ↓ td of image ↓ ---->
  <td id="bor" rowspan="1" colspan="2">
      <img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg"> 
  </td>
  <!---- ↑ td of image ↑ ---->
  <!---- ↓ td of table with text ↓ ---->
  <td>
      <table>
        <tbody>
           <tr id="pop">
             <td id="bor">차량 대여요금</td>
             <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
           </tr>
           <tr id="pop">
             <td id="bor">보험료</td>
             <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
           </tr>
           <tr id="pop">
             <td id="bor">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
             <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
           </tr>
           <tr id="pop">
              <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor"> 
              총 결제 금액</td>
              <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원 
              </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
     </td>
     <!---- ↑ td of table with text ↑ ---->
  </tr>
```

Working sample:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-head', function() {


      $('.accordion-head').removeClass('open');
      if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).addClass('open1');
      } else {
        $('.accordion-head').removeClass('open');
        $(this).addClass('close');
      }
      $('.accordion-body').slideUp("fast");
      $(this).next().slideDown("fast");

      $(document).on('dblclick', '.accordion-head', function() {

        if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
          $('.accordion-head').removeClass('open1');
        } else {
          $('.accordion-head').removeClass('open');
          $(this).addClass('close');
        }
        $('.accordion-body').slideUp("fast");
      });
    });
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 860px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.main-title {
  margin-top: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

hr.garo {
  border: 1px solid #757272;
  margin: 17px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#tableMain {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

th,
td {

  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

#pop {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left
}

/***** ↓↓ EDIT: added this css ↓↓ *****/
#pop > td {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
/***** ↑↑ EDIT: added this css ↑↑ *****/

#tableMain>img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
}



#bor {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pay {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.418);
}

.breakrow {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}

input {
  background-color: #ffc107;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;

}

#sep {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;

}

#space {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 60;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.arrow {
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-top-color: lightgray;
  transition: 350ms;
  position: absolute;
}

.accordion-head.open {
  background: white;
}

.accordion-head.open1 {
  background: #eee;
}

.accordion-head.open .arrow {
  margin-top: -10px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="outer">
  <span class="main-title">예약 내역 조회</span>
  <hr class="garo">

  <table id="tableMain" class="accordion" style="text-align:center;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="height:40px;">예약 번호</th>
        <th style="height:40px;">대여 기간</th>
        <th style="height:40px; padding-right:90px;">지점명</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="accordion-head breakrow open">
        <td>
          <div class="arrow"></div> 1
        </td>
        <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
        <td>강남지점-강남지점 <input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""></td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-body" style="display: none;">
        <td colspan="3">
          <table id="sep">
            <tbody>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor" rowspan="1" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg">

                </td>
                <td>
                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td id="bor">차량 대여요금</td>
                        <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td id="bor">보험료</td>
                        <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td id="bor">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                        <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor">총 결제 금액</td>
                        <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Number #2 -->
      <tr class="accordion-head breakrow open">
        <td>
          <div class="arrow"></div> 1
        </td>
        <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
        <td>강남지점-강남지점 <input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""></td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-body" style="display: none;">
        <td colspan="3">
          <table id="sep">
            <tbody>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor" rowspan="1" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg">

                </td>
                <td>
                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td id="bor">차량 대여요금</td>
                        <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td id="bor">보험료</td>
                        <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td id="bor">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                        <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor">총 결제 금액</td>
                        <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr><tr class="accordion-head breakrow open">
        <td>
          <div class="arrow"></div> 1
        </td>
        <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
        <td>강남지점-강남지점 <input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""></td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-body" style="display: none;">
        <td colspan="3">
          <table id="sep">
            <tbody>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor" rowspan="1" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg">

                </td>
                <td>
                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td id="bor">차량 대여요금</td>
                        <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td id="bor">보험료</td>
                        <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td id="bor">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                        <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor">총 결제 금액</td>
                        <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr><tr class="accordion-head breakrow open">
        <td>
          <div class="arrow"></div> 1
        </td>
        <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
        <td>강남지점-강남지점 <input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""></td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-body" style="display: none;">
        <td colspan="3">
          <table id="sep">
            <tbody>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor" rowspan="1" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg">

                </td>
                <td>
                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td id="bor">차량 대여요금</td>
                        <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td id="bor">보험료</td>
                        <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td id="bor">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                        <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr id="pop">
                        <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor">총 결제 금액</td>
                        <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, that is what i want to get while I want to keep the table on the bottom of the image as I posted a picture. Thank you tho!